# Expected payoff of four dice

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

Saw this interview question on a forum, I'm stuck in the way that I thought the order of rolling the four dice should not influence the expected value as they are independent anyway?

Question: There are four six-sided dice, rolled independently by four players, one after the other. Say the i-th person rolls $X_i$, i.e. $X_1$ is the result rolled by the first person, $X_2$ rolled second... etc.

Let $X_{(1)} \leq X_{(2)} \leq X_{(3)} \leq X_{(4)}$ represent the four rolls in increasing value, they are not necessarily rolled in this order, i.e. $X_{(1)}$ need not be $X_{1}$.

Your payoff of this game is calculated by
$$\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(4)} - X_{(2)} -X_{(3)}}{2}$$
that is, we group the highest and lowest roll, find their average, then subtract that by the average of the other group formed by the remaining rolls.

Given you are the second person to roll the dice, what value of $X_1$ would maximise your payoff?

Edit: clarity and context.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. It will be better if you post context _e.g._ the source of the problem, what you have tried, etc. (You can click on the edit button below the post to do so!) Otherwise the post will attract downvotes and closevotes.

Comment: What you mean by "what number should the first player's roll be," is not clear to me. The suffixes you have given are for value. Where are those for order ?

Comment: Thanks for the tips @ultralegend5385, I've added a brief sentence at the start for context.

Comment: @trueblueanil, the bracketed suffixes in the question dictate that the rolls are in increasing value. I have added a distinction between the unbracketed and bracketed suffixes in hopes of clarifying the notation. The bracketed suffix simply means that we order the dice rolls in ascending order.

Comment: Guess: Since we want to maximize $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(4)}$, while minimizing $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(3)}$, I guess the unordered result $\{1, 1, 1, 6\}$ is maximizing the payoff. So I guess $1$ will maximize

Comment: The way you have put it, everyone's payoff would be the same so what difference does rolling second in order make ?